# Separating data in an Excel sheet into different worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have to write a code in macros to separate a an Excel sheet containing 2,00,000 rows into 10 different worksheets containing 20,000 rows each.

I have tried to create 10 different workbooks to start off with. Here's the code for the same:

```
Sub AddNew()

Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To 10
    Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add
        With NewBook
             .Title = "Employee Details[i]"
             .Subject = "Employees[i]"
             .SaveAs Filename = "Employee_Details[i].xls"
        End With 
Next i

End Sub
```

The problem is there's only one workbook that is being created. Any suggestions/solution would be highly appreciated :)

Comment: Have you tried anything? If so, please post the code and any issues you may have with it. Otherwise I suggest you do some research and edit your question when you have a code related problem.

Comment: Hi, I have started off with writing a code to create 10 workbooks. But there seems to be a problem. There's only one new excel workbook that is being created instead of 10. Here's the code,                            Sub AddNew()
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 10
Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add
With NewBook
.Title = "Employee Details[i]"
.Subject = "Employees[i]"
.SaveAs Filename = "Employee_Details[i].xls"
End With
Next i
End Sub

Comment: Please edit the question to include the code.

Answer (score 0):

Okej, so this isn't a complete answer to your question. But it should get you a bit further. This code creates the workbooks and you can change it to suit your needs.

```
Sub testBook()

    Dim newBook As Workbook
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To 10
        Set newBook = Workbooks.Add
            With newBook
                .Title = "Employee Details " & i
                .Subject = "Employees " & i
                .SaveAs Filename:="Employee_Details" & i & ".xlsx"
            End With

        ''place code here to copy the content you want 
        ''into the new workbook before closing and createing

        newBook.Close

    Next i

End Sub
```

I would suggest you try this code and fix it so that it works for you. For example adding a different savepath and so on. You should find information about that without much trouble.

When you have gotten this to work, read up on how to copy a specific range to the new workbooks and see how far you get with that. If you run into problems you later post that as a new question.